# multi-threaded producer/consumer

Tags: c#, producer-consumer

I have a proxy server I'm writing in C#.  I also have a Java applet that receives MJPEG data from a video server through this C# proxy.  My problem is that when no more MJPEG data is currently available from the video server, the proxy is stuck in a blocking read call and I cannot terminate it.

```
// write the forwarded output
// blocking on remoteServerResponseStream.Read
while (m_running && (read = remoteServerResponseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    bytesRead += read;

    output.Write(buffer, 0, read);

    output.Flush();
}
```

This should be terminated by the Java applet closing the stream (variable `output` in code above).  However, the Java applet cannot close this connection because the proxy never acknowledges the close request while it is stuck in `remoteServerResponseStream.Read` waiting for data.

I have been stuck on this problem for a week.  I think I might have thought of a solution but I'm not sure if it will work.  I'd love to hear any feedback on this.

My thought was to have the `removeServerResponseStream.Read` on another thread and use a shared Queue to transfer data.  The thread would read data and place it on the queue.  My main thread would then forward any data available in the queue to `output`.  This way, I can constantly check if `output.CanWrite` ever becomes false, in which case I can abort the read thread (this is the only way I know of to interrupt a blocking stream read).  Is this a viable solution?  If so, should I constantly poll the queue for data available or should I create an event?  I'd love to hear any thoughts on this problem!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use the concurrent collection and other container classes introduced with .NET 4.0 Task Parallel Library.

Comment: We need additional code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these situations I just end the stream reader from another thread. When you close the reader it will break the loop.  Going through extra synchronized queues is just more boilerplate to do unnecessarily.  Eventually somewhere you have to stop the blocking reader. Putting values in a queue only stops your consumer from being blocked, but not your reader.

Here is an example with a socket blocking read. I will be blocking on reading 1 byte which I'll intentionally never send. A couple seconds later I'll dispose of the socket, the socket will bail out of its blocking read and the app will exit gracefully.  I'll log what each thread is doing and when it happens (the number prefixing each log line is the thread id and I'll indent separate threads).

In your class that uses the blocking reader you should implement the Disposable pattern and close/dispose of your reader there.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SocketTest();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void SocketTest()
{
    int port = 22345;

    var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

    tcpListener.Start();

    // Listening thread
    new Thread(() =>
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - Waiting for connection to port");

        var socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();

        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - Connection accepted");

        var stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - Starting blocking read");
            var bytes = reader.ReadBytes(1);
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - Done blocking read, read {0} bytes", bytes.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error reading " + ex);
        }
    }).Start();

    // connecting thread
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        Console.WriteLine("\t" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - Connecting to local port");

        socket.Connect("127.0.0.1", port);

        Console.WriteLine("\t" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - Connecting to local succeeded");

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        Console.WriteLine("\t" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - Disposing of socket");

        socket.Dispose();

    }).Start();

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}
```

When you run this you get:

```
3 - Waiting for connection to port
        4 - Connecting to local port
        4 - Connecting to local succeeded
3 - Connection accepted
3 - Starting blocking read
        4 - Disposing of socket
3 - Done blocking read, read 0 bytes
Press any key to exit
```

You kind of answered the question yourself here though:

> My thought was to have the removeServerResponseStream.Read on another thread

Which is exactly what you should do. When you know your app has closed close the socket from the active thread. This free's the blocked thread and you can gracefully end.

The pattern here is you usually spin up a thread for a specific socket and you maintain one active thread that is a kind of "controller" thread for requests.

Comment: My problem is I don't know WHEN to dispose of the socket.  When a video clip ends, the video server stops sending data but keeps the connection alive because the video server can receive commands to seek to a different position in the clip.  If it receives, for example, a command to seek the clip to the beginning, it just starts sending data over the same connection again.  So data not being sent over the connection doesn't necessarily mean we should close it.  I need to close the connection when the Java applet closes `output`.

Comment: Sounds like you do know when to dispose of the socket: when the applet closes.  If you have no deterministic way to know when your applet has disconnected you can assign a timeout on the socket. If you don't get any data in the known time the socket will close automatically, but then you'll be at the mercy of having to reconnect if that value is incorrect.  Can you have your applet have a ping? If the ping isn't received in a certain amount of time a controller thread can close the corresponding open socket.

Comment: so then I'm kinda of stuck using a shared queue, right?  To pass data from my read thread to my "consumer" or "output" thread?  Also, if I close the connection from the Java applet, will an exception be raised in my "output" thread, and from there I can properly dispose of the read socket?  BTW, thanks for all the help, man.

Comment: No, look at my example. No exceptions are raised, this is standard socket close procedure.  You don't need a shared queue, just because data is in another thread doesn't mean you have to queue it.  Your objects are shared in threads.  If all you're doing is reading data and then writing it out as long as that writer isn't used in another thread you are fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help devshorts.